# What view(s) can I use in order to create something like the about screen of the phone?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-view

I want to write an activity that is similar to the about screen of android phones. I want it to display some information in the style of the about screen of android phones. 
Like this

```
title1
info
-----------------
title2
info
-----------------
etc.
```

Is there a special view that I can use or is it just a result of multiple views placed in a specific way? Or is there an activity template in android studio that I can use?

Comment: You can use a LIstView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) or [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html). They are special list views populated either from code or from a xml file. There are many different preference types to choose from (checkbox, switch, list etc)

An example preference fragment:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this for settings? I just want to show stuff. Or I can use this to show stuff too?

Comment: @Sweeper You can use it for whatever you want, it's been built for settings yes, but for example I made a chat app which used this inside the left drawer for a list of all online users. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/3DAvYVF.png) ("Online Korisnici" means "Online users"), while the above were custom added sections by enabled plugins (except the login button)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ListView`. You can create a custom layout for cells and then use an array or a cursor to fill the data.

> ListView: A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list. The
>   items come from the ListAdapter associated with this view.

`ListAdapter` can receive data as input. The adapter would inflate the layout for each cell in its `getView()` method and assign the data to the individual views in the cell.

Read more about `ListView` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ListView` and a custom `ArrayAdapter` to create a screen like that. If you need any help about how to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` check this useful tutorial [here](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a simple list, then `ListView` is probably the simplest option. You may also want to look into `ListActivity` and/or `ListFragment` as well to further simplify the process.

If you intend to use complex animations, or have the list update dynamically with animations, you may be better served with `RecyclerView`, although using it is more complex.

An straightforward implementation of `ListActivity` could look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] titles = { "title one", "title two" };
String[] descriptions = { "desc 1", "desc 2" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter() {
```

leave everything the same, except for `getCount()` and `getView()`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titles.length;
}
```

This will ensure you list is always the correct length as your array.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

    title.setText(titles[position]);
    description.setText(descriptions[position]);

    return view;
}
```

And `row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```